# Show that $l^2(\Bbb N , F)$ with equipped norm is not complete.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

For $v$ in $l^2(\Bbb N , F)$ with norm on $l^2$ defined as:
 $\lvert\lvert v\rvert\rvert_{W}= \sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{\lvert v_{[k]}\rvert}{2^k}$

Show that $l^2(\Bbb N , F)$ with the norm  $\lvert\lvert v\rvert\rvert_{W}$ is not complete.

I believe that I need to find a Cauchy sequence on $l^2$ which does not converge in $l^2$ but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Check your post and ask yourself whether it can be understood by somebody who is not you.

Comment: you probably want $|v_k|$ instead of $v_k$ only.

Comment: No. In order that a question be understood it is necessary that all symbols are defined/explained.

Comment: I've edited for clarity, is it understandable now?

Comment: Maybe I'm just dumb, but what exactly is the $F$ in your notation? Do you just want to talk about the sequences which are square-summable with a different norm?

Comment: I believe that F is just a general field but I do think that I jsut want to talk about the sequences which are square-summable with a different norm! I'm just very stuck on how to go about this